# Difference between html input pattern and angular ngPattern?

Tags: angularjs

I notice some developers are using html input pattern for validation in an angular styled form:

```
<input id="email" name="email"
    type="text"
    ng-model="vm.contact.mail"
    pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$"
    required />

<span ng-show="!vm.contact.email.$error.required && 
    vm.contact.email.$error.pattern && 
    vm.contact.email.$dirty">
    Email is not in the correct format.</span>
```

It appears to work the same with

```
ng-pattern="/[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$/"
```

Are those two ways indeed interchangeable? Is there any advantage/preference for one over the other in the usage or performance?

Answer (score 8):

**Form validation**

Both options will trigger form validation, since ng-pattern is just converted to pattern (tested).

**Difference**

There is just a slight difference between `ng-pattern` and `pattern`. According to the documentation ng-pattern also allows you to pass Regexp expressions defined in your scope. Also, ng-pattern will not trigger default browser validation (red border, error message around input).

So you can decide whenever you want to have default browser validation in your application or not.

[Example plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/O3RDTSi06iVNEj9jfLx4?p=preview) showing both in action.